# How to remove comma in scrapy output

Tags: python, scrapy

I am working on a scrapy spider. Here my code :

```
item = MyItem()
item['Description'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="textepresentation"]//p').extract()
item['Description'] = [ '\,'.join(field.split(',')) for field in item.get('Description', [])]
```

I get this result :

```
 [ u'<p>Some text.</p>',
             u'<p>\xa0</p>',
             u'<p>\xa0</p>',
             u'<p>\xa0</p>',
  u'<p>Some other text.</p>',
              u'<p>\xa0</p>',
              u'<p>\xa0</p>'],
```

I want to remove empty `<p> </p>` tags :

```
item['Description'] = [ ''.join(field.replace('<p>'u'\xa0''</p>', '').encode('utf-8')) for field in item.get('Description', [])]
```

and i get this result :

```
['<p>Some text.</p>',
             '',
             '',
             '',
 '<p>Some other text.</p>',
             '',
             ''],
```

Now,  how can i remove the comma in the result to get this ?

```
['<p>Some text.</p>'
 '<p>Some other text</p>']
```

Comment: @alecxe I edited my question. Let us say i have a list of <p> tags and some of them are empty. I  removed these empty <p> tags and now i want to remove the comma in my output.

Comment: @alecxe I want to keep the html but not empty <p>

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the `text()` and call `extract_first()`:

```
response.xpath('//*[@id="textepresentation"]//p/text()').extract_first()
```